# Ember.js - Reload paginated list from API after model deletion (and probably insertion)

Tags: api, ember.js, metadata, reload

I have a paginated list of models which comes from my REST api.
I use the api's pagination metadata to get the total number of records from my DB, and see if there are previous or next pages.
If I delete one of the records on the current page, I would like several things to happen:
- The first record of the next page should appear in the current page (if it exists).
- My metadata to be updated. (Total and pagination data)

The direct transitionToRoute method on the controller is not doing any of that. I believe an API reload of the current page is the way to go, but it doesn't seem implemented as far as I know.

I have managed to get the result I want by doing self.transitionToRoute('index') followed by another self.transitionToRoute to the page I want reloaded... This is downright horrible and makes me cringe. There must be a better way!

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
//router.js
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('jobs', function(){
    this.resource('job', { path:'/:job_id' }, function(){
      this.route('edit');
    });
    this.route('create');
  });
});

//mixins.js
App.PaginatedListController = Ember.Mixin.create({
    queryParams: ['page'],
    page: 1,
    total: function(){
        return this.get('meta').count;
    }.property('meta'),
    previousAPIPage: function(){
        return this.get('meta').previous;
    }.property('meta'),
    nextAPIPage: function(){
        return this.get('meta').next;
    }.property('meta'),
    hasPreviousPage: function(){
        return this.get('previousAPIPage') ? true : false;
    }.property('previousAPIPage'),
    hasNextPage: function(){
        return this.get('nextAPIPage') ? true : false;
    }.property('nextAPIPage'),
    actions:{
        previousPage: function(){
            this.decrementProperty('page');
            this.transitionToRoute({
                queryParams: {
                    page: this.get('page')
                }
            });
        },
        nextPage: function(){
            this.incrementProperty('page');
            this.transitionToRoute({
                queryParams: {
                    page: this.get('page')
                }
            });
        },
    },
});

//controllers\jobController.js
App.JobsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(App.PaginatedListController, {
  sortProperties: ['name'],
  sortAscending: true,
  meta: function(){
      return this.store.metadataFor('job');
  }.property('model.@each')
});

App.JobController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['jobs'],
    deleteMode: false,
    actions: {
        delete: function(){
            // our delete method now only toggles deleteMode's value
            this.toggleProperty('deleteMode');
        },
        cancelDelete: function(){
            // set deleteMode back to false
            this.set('deleteMode', false);
        },
        confirmDelete: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.set('deleteMode', false);
            this.get('model').destroyRecord().then(function(response) {
                var qParams = self.get('controllers.jobs').get('queryParams');
                //This is where it hurts
                self.transitionToRoute('index');
                //This is what I want reloaded
                self.transitionToRoute('jobs', {queryParams:qParams});
            });
        },
    }
});
```